# inttypes.h not found in arm-none-eabi-gcc

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, include, lpc

I have a header file in a library which includes inttypes.h (required for using PRIu8, etc.). I am including the library header file into my own application file.

When I try to compile using arm-none-eabi-gcc in lpcxpresso(based on eclipse), I get the error

```
inttypes.h: No such file or directory
```

The build command is

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -std=c99 -DDEBUG -D__CODE_RED -DCORE_M3 -D__USE_CMSIS=CMSISv1p30_LPC17xx -D__LPC17XX__ -D__REDLIB__ -I"some include" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -fno-builtin -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -D__REDLIB__ -specs=redlib.specs -MMD -MP -MF"src/KISS_Server.d" -MT"src/KISS_Server.o" -MT"src/KISS_Server.d" -o "src/KISS_Server.o" "../src/KISS_Server.c"
```

Why am I getting this error?

I'm trying to compile for the LPC1769 which has a Cortex-M3 processor

Comment: have you tried `find /usr/inclue -name inttypes.h`?

Comment: That shall give me the includes if I was building for x86 on linux, right? However, since I am building for arm, so that would be a different file, right?

Comment: I do find  ~/Documents/LPCX/lpcxpresso/tools/arm-none-eabi/include/c++/4.9.3/tr1/inttypes.h and 
~/Documents/LPCX/lpcxpresso/tools/arm-none-eabi/include/inttypes.h

 though

Comment: Try adding the include path to the compiler command like `-I${HOME}/Documents/LPCX/lpcxpresso/tools/arm-none-eabi/include`.

Comment: @iharob - That should work, but I am looking for a more elegant solution which exposes the underlying problem. 

Under -std=c99, the compiler should not complain about inttypes.h

Comment: The standard has absolutely no relation to where the headers are in the filesystem, which appears to be your problem, the compiler has a default searching path for headers which you can check with `cpp -Wp,-v` if the file is not in that path, it simply **will not be found** by the compiler no matter if you use `-std=c11` or `-std=c89` it doesn't matter, the include files are just files the standard has nothing to do with that.

Comment: Read my answer. A freestanding evironment as defined by the standard need not provide inttypes.h (and may other headers and all libraries).

Comment: @Olaf - Except that arm-none-eabi does provide inttypes.h. It is there in the folder tools/arm-none-eabi/include. I just have to figure out why Eclipse is not searching that directory.

Comment: Well, no, it does not. It actually comes with newlib, which makes pretty much sense, if you think about it. Because gcc does not provide printf & co (stdlib); that would be - tara! - newlib ;-). However, it is very well possible your tools pack it into the same directory (mine is in /usr for instance).

Answer (score 1):

The headers are optional on a freestanding environment (n1570, 5.1.2.1) as for arm-none-eabi. No idea which host you use, but on Ubuntu 14.04, the headers are in /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.2/include for gcc and only includes few headers. That makes sense, as there is no stdlib which would provide printf & co.

However, you can also use newlib, which provides stdlib and also inttypes.h. Also, check the include (and library) paths.

Comment: See comments above. I can find inttypes.h in my LPCXpresso arm-none-eabi tools directory. I guess I should try using newlib though

Comment: @TSG: I happily use the standard packages provided, but I don't use Eclipse or any other IDE (SCons support is missing on those and actually no need). Admitted, its just 4.8.x, but that's enough for now and I'm just tired of installing manually (on Kubuntu 12.04 I had to and it was quite a hassle until I used sumon-arm-toolchain).

Comment: I am part of a team that uses Eclipse and my project has to be easily portable for everyone. Writing a makefile is possible but not a good option.

Comment: @TSG: That's why we use SCons, not make. Major parts of the code are auto-generated, requiring build-system information (e.g. dependencies) and automatic module selection. An IDE would not make much difference compared to a good editor, so: no need.

Comment: I tried using newlib. Did not help. I appreciate your suggestion to use a build tool. I will see if it is possible

Comment: @TSG: Build tool or development toolchain?

Comment: SCons is what I meant

Comment: @TSG: Just a kind warning: I prefer a Jaguar/Lotus over Rolls Royce/Porsche (mostly not for the speed, but for keeping contact to the road). Som, for build, I use SCons and self-written Python code (auto-collect modules, code generation, etc.). For compilation, I would stick to the (K)Ubuntu standard packages. These include newlib, gcc and binutils straight from the packages (arm-none-eabi-*). Editor I leave to you, I use KWrite(!); Kate looks promising. And - of course - the console. Still faster with that than most others with IDEs.

Comment: Yes, SCons is a build tool. But I do not know an IDE which does support it like most (all?) support make.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add --sysroot= CFLAGS to your gcc command.
It will take affects on headers and libraries searching.